# Application Menu Crash when Searching App

Tags: slingshot

I edited the Applications Menu with Alacarte (Main Menu), Now when I search for any app from slingshot, Wingpanel Crashes.

here are the debug info:

```
skb50bd@ROG:~$ killall wingpanel
skb50bd@ROG:~$ wingpanel
[INFO 04:36:45.071750] Application.vala:155: System Panel version: 2.0.1
[INFO 04:36:45.071777] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 4.4.0-36-generic
[FATAL 04:36:45.170516] wingpanel_widgets_overlay_icon_set_main_icon_name: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
[FATAL 04:36:45.170800] wingpanel_widgets_overlay_icon_set_main_icon_name: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
[22:36:45.246899 GLib-GIO-Critical] g_file_get_child: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
[22:36:45.246917 GLib-GIO-Critical] g_file_query_exists: assertion 'G_IS_FILE(file)' failed
[22:36:45.246922 GLib-GIO-Critical] g_file_get_child: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
[22:36:45.246926 GLib-GIO-Critical] g_file_query_exists: assertion 'G_IS_FILE(file)' failed
[22:36:45.246932 Critical] gee_abstract_collection_get_size: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
[22:36:45.246937 Warning] Theme.vala:508: Currently selected gtk+ theme 'elementary' does not provide a dock theme, fallback to the built-in defaults!
[22:36:45.301845 Gtk-Warning] Attempting to add a widget with type AyatanaCompatibilityIndicatorButton to a container of type GtkRevealer, but the widget is already inside a container of type GtkRevealer, please remove the widget from its existing container first.
[22:36:45.301870 Gtk-Warning] Attempting to add a widget with type GtkStack to a container of type WingpanelWidgetsIndicatorPopover, but the widget is already inside a container of type WingpanelWidgetsIndicatorPopover, please remove the widget from its existing container first.
[22:36:45.303046 GLib-Critical] g_hash_table_get_keys: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
[22:36:45.484345 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to create AppInfo
[22:36:45.487711 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to create AppInfo
[22:36:45.490333 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to create AppInfo
[22:36:45.509954 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to create AppInfo
[22:36:45.514932 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to create AppInfo
[22:36:45.525217 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Key file does not have key 'Type' in group 'Desktop Entry'
[22:36:45.533813 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to get exec for Other
[22:36:45.636385 Info] Tweaks.vala:68: Activating tweaks plug
[22:36:53.020589 GLib-GIO-Critical] g_desktop_app_info_list_actions: assertion 'G_IS_DESKTOP_APP_INFO (info)' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Please help me out here. 
Thanks.